# How to fix the following error i received of undefined reference

Tags: c++

I was getting an error of "undefined reference" to `gcd(long, long)`.

This is my `gcd.cc` file:

```cpp
#include <gcd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    long a,b;
    
    cout << "Enter the first number ---> ";

    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter the second number ---> ";

    cin >> b;
    
    cout <<"The gcd of " <<  a << " and " <<  b << " is "
         << gcd ( a, b) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is my `gcd.h` file:

```cpp
#ifndef GCD_H
#define GCD_H

long gcd (long a, long b) ;

#endif
```

Comment: Did you define `gcd` anywhere?

Comment: You are likely not compiling `gcd.cc` into an object file and then linking that into your final executable.

Comment: I guess i did not. Can you please guide where and how to define that?

Comment: Well, you need to write code that will be exeuted when `gcd` function is called. I.e., you need to write how to calculate that gcd.

Comment: How to link a file depends on the build tools you're using. It could be something simple like `g++ gcd. cc file_that_defines_gcd.cc`, but it could be "click this, then click that and select this option and then type a bit."

Comment: I am loving this run of declared-but-not-implemented functions. I hadn't seen this until yesterday, but this is the third one I've seen since then.

Comment: Thank You so much for helping everyone